# How do I find average difference between a sequence of timestamps in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an *unordered* sequence of timestamps. I need to be able calculate *min*, *max* and *average* difference between every subsequent timestamps. e.g. given:

```
DateTimeOffset now = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));
DateTimeOffset[] timestamps = new[] {
    now,
    now.AddSeconds(5),
    now.AddSeconds(10),
    now.AddSeconds(15),
    now.AddSeconds(30),
    now.AddSeconds(31)
};
    
IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset> timestampsSorted = timestamps.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Should produce:

```
2022-01-01 00:00:31->2022-01-01 00:00:30 | 00:00:01
2022-01-01 00:00:30->2022-01-01 00:00:15 | 00:00:15
2022-01-01 00:00:15->2022-01-01 00:00:10 | 00:00:05
2022-01-01 00:00:10->2022-01-01 00:00:05 | 00:00:05
2022-01-01 00:00:05->2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 00:00:05

Min 00:00:01
Max 00:00:15
Avg 00:00:06.2000000
```

The procedural solution I have come up with is below, it would be great if I can simplify this using LINQ.

```
TimeSpan min = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
TimeSpan max = TimeSpan.MinValue;
List<TimeSpan> deltas = new();

for (int i = timestampsSorted.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    DateTimeOffset later = timestamps[i];
    DateTimeOffset prev = timestamps[i - 1];

    TimeSpan delta = later - prev;
    
    if (delta > max) { max = delta; }
    if (delta < min) { min = delta; }

    deltas.Add(delta);
    Console.WriteLine($"{later:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}->{prev:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | {delta}");
}

var result = new { 
    Min = min,
    Max = max,
    Avg = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(deltas.Average(d => d.TotalMilliseconds))
};
```

Comment: Are you aware that `deltas.Average()` will throw an exception and `min` and `max` will be unchanged when `timestamps.Length` is `0` or `1`?  Also, `i` should be initialized to `timestamps.Length - 1` since `timestampsSorted` is an `IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset>`, which has no `Length` property.

Answer (score 1):

Using `LINQ`'s built-in `Min`, `Max` and `Average` functions.

```
var timestampsSorted = timestamps.OrderByDescending(o => o).ToArray();
var data = timestampsSorted
    .Skip(1)
    .Select((o, i) => timestampsSorted[i] - o)
    .ToArray();
var min = data.Min();
var max = data.Max();
var avg = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(data.Average(o => o.TotalSeconds));
```

Note that the separate calls to these `Min`, `Max` and `Average` functions result in 3 iterations over the items in the `data` array.

Comment: This is functionally the same but, as noted, does not perform the same; you might as well stick with the `for` loop.  Also, `Min()`, `Max()`, and `Average()` would each throw an exception if `timestamps` contains less than 2 elements.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews True about the loop count, hence my note.
But if `timestamps` would have less than 2 elements then there's no need to do any of the calculations since each timestamp needs to compared with its subsequent one; so no exception would be thrown.

Comment: But an exception would be thrown because this code doesn't handle that case whereas in the original the loop would not be entered.  You and I may know that there's no need to calculate the min/max/average of 0 or 1 elements, but this code doesn't.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews I don't disagree. But wouldn't the code in the question crash on `deltas.Average` in the same way if there are no timestamps? And the `min` and `max` set to `TimeSpan.MaxValue` and `TimeSpan.MinValue` wouldn't be correct neither. I tend to say an answer doesn't have to provide the full program code, but just the part OP is asking for, which is a matching `LINQ` setup. A +6k OP will be able to handle the rest just fine.

Comment: Thanks @pfx. Yes I skipped a few things here for brevity. I managed to utilize _.Aggregate_ to calcualte all three in one pass but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from optimal as the collection is enumerated several times, but because you asked...

```
// Expensive, multiple enumeration
var diffs = timestampsSorted.Skip(1).Zip(timestampsSorted, (first, second) => second.Subtract(first));
Console.WriteLine($"Min = {timestampsSorted.Min():ss.fff}, Max = {timestampsSorted.Max():ss.fff}, Ave = {diffs.Select(t => t.TotalMilliseconds).Average() / 1000:0.000}");
```

Ref: [Zip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) and [Skip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

First, the date difference with the next item is calculated and stored in the `diff` list:

```
var diff = timestampsSorted.Select(x => x- ((timestampsSorted.IndexOf(x) + 1)< timestampsSorted.Count?
           timestampsSorted[timestampsSorted.IndexOf(x) + 1]: now) ).ToList();
diff.RemoveAt(diff.Count-1);
```

> 00:00:01
> 00:00:15
> 00:00:05
> 00:00:05
> 00:00:05

And then the `mean`, `max` and `average` are easily calculated:

```
Console.WriteLine("Min {0}",diff.Min());

Console.WriteLine("Max {0}", diff.Max());

var averageDates = (long)diff.Select(d => d.Ticks).Average();
Console.WriteLine("Avg {0}", new DateTime(averageDates).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

> Min 00:00:01
> Max 00:00:15
> Avg 00:00:06.200

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to store all of the `delta` values in a `List<TimeSpan>` on which to call `Average()`; it's more efficient to just keep a running sum and then divide it by the number of pairs compared (`timestamps.Length - 1`).  So this...

```csharp
// ...
List<TimeSpan> deltas = new();

for (int i = timestamps.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    // ...
    deltas.Add(delta);
    // ...
}

var result = new {
    // ...
    Avg = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(deltas.Average(d => d.TotalMilliseconds))
};
```

...would be changed to...

```csharp
// ...
TimeSpan sum = TimeSpan.Zero;

for (int i = timestamps.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    // ...
    sum += delta;
    // ...
}

var result = new { 
    // ...
    //TODO: Avoid division for sequences with less than 2 elements, if expected
    Avg = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(sum.TotalMilliseconds / (timestamps.Length - 1))
};
```

[`Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) is what you'd use to accumulate one or more values over the course of a sequence.  Here's a method that uses `Aggregate()` to calculate the same values as your `for` loop...

```csharp
static (TimeSpan? Minimum, TimeSpan? Maximum, TimeSpan? Average, int Count) GetDeltaStatistics(IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset> timestamps)
{
    var seed = (
        Previous: (DateTimeOffset?) null,
        Minimum: (TimeSpan?) null,
        Maximum: (TimeSpan?) null,
        Sum: TimeSpan.Zero,
        Count: 0
    );

    return timestamps.Aggregate(
        seed,
        (accumulator, current) => {
            if (accumulator.Previous != null)
            {
                TimeSpan delta = current - accumulator.Previous.Value;

                if (++accumulator.Count > 1)
                {
                    // This is not the first comparison; Minimum and Maximum are non-null
                    if (delta < accumulator.Minimum.Value)
                        accumulator.Minimum = delta;
                    if (delta > accumulator.Maximum.Value)
                        accumulator.Maximum = delta;
                }
                else
                {
                    // No prior comparisons have been performed
                    // Minimum and Maximum must be null so unconditionally overwrite them
                    accumulator.Minimum = accumulator.Maximum = delta;
                }
                accumulator.Sum += delta;

                Console.WriteLine($"{current:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}->{accumulator.Previous:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | {delta}");
            }
            accumulator.Previous = current;

            return accumulator;
        },
        accumulator => (
            accumulator.Minimum,
            accumulator.Maximum,
            Average: accumulator.Count > 0
                ? new TimeSpan(accumulator.Sum.Ticks / accumulator.Count)
                : (TimeSpan?) null,
            accumulator.Count
        )
    );
}
```

The second parameter of this overload of `Aggregate()` is a `Func<>` that is passed the current element in the sequence (`current`) and the state that was returned from the previous invocation of the `Func<>` (`accumulator`).  The first parameter provides the initial value of `accumulator`.  The third parameter is a `Func<>` that transforms the final value of this state to the return value of `Aggregate()`.  The state and return value are all [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).

Note that `GetDeltaStatistics()` only needs an `IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset>` and not a `IList<DateTimeOffset>` or `DateTimeOffset[]`; since there is no random access to adjacent elements, though, the value of `current` is carried forward to the next invocation via `accumulator.Previous`.  I also made it the caller's responsibility to provide sorted input, but you could just as easily perform that inside the method.

Calling `GetDeltaStatistics()` with...

```csharp
static void Main()
{
    DateTimeOffset now = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    DateTimeOffset[] timestamps = new[] {
        now,
        now.AddSeconds(5),
        now.AddSeconds(10),
        now.AddSeconds(15),
        now.AddSeconds(30),
        now.AddSeconds(31)
    };

    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset>> timestampSequences = new IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset>[] {
        timestamps,
        timestamps.Take(2),
        timestamps.Take(1),
        timestamps.Take(0)
    };
    foreach (IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset> sequence in timestampSequences)
    {
        var (minimum, maximum, average, count) = GetDeltaStatistics(sequence.OrderBy(offset => offset));

        Console.WriteLine($"Minimum: {GetDisplayText(minimum)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Maximum: {GetDisplayText(maximum)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Average: {GetDisplayText(average)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Count: {count}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

static string GetDisplayText(TimeSpan? delta) => delta == null ? "(null)" : delta.Value.ToString();
```

...produces this output...

```
2022-01-01 00:00:05->2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 00:00:05
2022-01-01 00:00:10->2022-01-01 00:00:05 | 00:00:05
2022-01-01 00:00:15->2022-01-01 00:00:10 | 00:00:05
2022-01-01 00:00:30->2022-01-01 00:00:15 | 00:00:15
2022-01-01 00:00:31->2022-01-01 00:00:30 | 00:00:01
Minimum: 00:00:01
Maximum: 00:00:15
Average: 00:00:06.2000000
  Count: 5

2022-01-01 00:00:05->2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 00:00:05
Minimum: 00:00:05
Maximum: 00:00:05
Average: 00:00:05
  Count: 1

Minimum: (null)
Maximum: (null)
Average: (null)
  Count: 0

Minimum: (null)
Maximum: (null)
Average: (null)
  Count: 0
```

Whereas the original code would cause an exception to be thrown, for sequences with less than two elements the result has a `Count` of `0` and the other fields are `null`.

Comment: Hrm.  Writing LINQ code that is both simpler than the `for` loop and (close to) as efficient as the `for` loop seems like competing interests; maybe there is a better way but this is at least a start.  I could have written this to operate on a `IList<DateTimeOffset>` but this way saves having to call `ToArray()` after ordering; the code in the question doesn't call it, either, but then also it mixes up the two `timestamps*` variables, so who knows what the baseline for comparison is.